# Is there a way to test an application on a real device without publishing?

Tags: android

Is there a way to test the application on the real device without publishing to Android market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be easily done. just connect the phone to you computer, install the drivers that come with the SDK.

Now if you are using eclipse then just go to the "run configuration" of your project and select manual in the Target tab. Now when you run your application through eclipse you will get to select the device on which to run the application and there you can see your device.

Alternatively, the same can be done via command line by typing `adb install <app_name>` and the application will automatically be installed to you phone. While using command line make sure that you are not sunning any emulators, else adb will give an error since it will confused on where to install the application.

Comment: Thanks, Also I want to install the application on another device. There is no eclipse. How to install the application ? I've found the post related this issue. 

(http://androidforums.com/t-mobile-mytouch-3g/18657-best-way-load-apk-file-touch-3g.html)
 
But I am not sure it is better way. Can you suggest to me another better way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to install the apk by just hosting it on a local server and opening the link in the android browser. it automatically started the installation of the apk after installation. If you want to distribute it to many people at the same time you can do it this way. 

I haven't tried bluetooth tranfering the apk. Maybe you can give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

On a device, turn on debug mode (in the Applications menu under Settings). When you plug your device in, it will show up alongside your emulators. If you have no booted emulators, running or debugging your app will automatically default to your device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about How to install the application to the device ?

Comment: Once USB debug mode is enabled, you install an app as you usually do, like Funkyidol described.